# Which number comes next?

Tags: number-sequence

This one should be easy. Easy as pie. Unless you think too hard.

> 9, 5, 3, 5, 6, 2, 9, 5, 1, 4, 1, ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is

> The digits of Pi backwards, 3.14159265359

So the missing number would be

> 3

And,

> You said it would be "easy as pie"

Comment: This was my guess as well.